# Lagrange multipliers, critical points, eigenvectors

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, optimization, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, lagrange-multiplier

I have some difficulties proving this question:
Let $A \in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be symmetric, and consider critical points of $f(x) = Ax\cdot x$ subject to the constraint $\|x\| = 1.$ Prove that critical points are precisely the unit eigenvectors of $A$.

I have a hint saying that:  You may find it easier to write the constraint as $\|x\|^2 = 1$.

I tried to use Lagrange multipliers to prove this:

$\nabla f(x)= \lambda \nabla g(x)$, where $g(x)=\|x\|^2$. And I get $\nabla g(x)=2x$.
But then I don't know how to continue my proof. Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what $\nabla f(x)$ is?

Comment: @user17945 No.. I tried to write $f(x)$ in double sum form, but I don't know how to get $\nabla f(x)$

Comment: Ok. Well if you write $f(x) = \sum_{i,j=1}^nA_{ij}x_ix_j$, what is $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x^k}$, bearing in mind that $\frac{\partial x_i}{\partial x_k} = \delta_{ik}$. If it's not clear, it might help to consider the $n=2$ case first.

Comment: @user17945 Oh, I just derived that $\nabla f(x)=2 Ax$, so from the ∇()=∇(), I can get Ax=x. Is that right?

Comment: Yes. So the $x$'s are eigenvectors, and you then just use the constraint to say they're unit eigenvectors.

Comment: @user17945 Thanks! Solved!